# Next 13 Postgres client connection occurs after server components

Tags: database, postgresql, next.js, react-server-components

I have a Next.js 13 project with the app directory which connects successfully to a postgres database.

What I want to do is to connect to Postgres once, and then export the connection across my app so I will be able to perform queries from server components.

in order to do that I create a file, `index.ts`:

```js
import { VercelPoolClient, db } from '@vercel/postgres';

let client: VercelPoolClient | null = null

export async function connectToDB() {
    try {
        const establishClient = await db.connect();
        console.log('Connection to Postgres has established');
        client = establishClient
        return client
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('ERROR! Could not connect to Postgres');
        console.log(e);
        
    }
}
connectToDB()

export default function dbClient(): VercelPoolClient | null{
    if (!client) {
        throw new Error('you must connect before trying to use client')
    }
    return client
}
```

The problem seems that the connection to the Postgres database only occurs after my server components are already rendered, because I get an error from `dbClient()` but slightly afterwards, I do see the message from `console.log('Connection to Postgres has established');`.

I tried moving this file in and out of my app directory but the result is the same.
If anyone knows how can I ensure a connection has been established before the server components, that would be great.